# WCF not compiled to console app in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, wcf

I create WCF client Simple Example in Visual Studio 2010.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
string returnString;

while (true)
{
   try
   {
      string tt = Console.ReadLine();
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
      returnString = client.GetData(tt);

      Console.WriteLine(returnString);
      Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - dt);
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
}
```

If run project ctrl+f5 - error! Write me not enter point or bad format soap.

Else if run project f5 - all right!

Comment: Please share your service code

Comment: Post the exception that occured - preferably including stack trace. Is it perhaps `InvalidOperationException` and you have a library with it's own .config?

Comment: Is your service project part of the solution from which you start the client?

Answer (score 0):

You've got the code for a service client, but you'll also need the service to be running in order for the client to connect to it. As you say you've created a simple example in Visual Studio, it seems likely that you've got a solution that has a project for the service and a project for the client.

If this is the case, you just need to run them both at the same time. Right-click on the Solution in the Solution Explorer window, and select "Set StartUp Projects...". You'll want the "Mutiple startup projects" option selected. For the service and the client projects, just change the Action to either "Start" or "Start without debugging", depending on what you want.

If your service project is in a different solution from the client, or if it's hosted elsewhere, just ensure it's running when you start the client.